# ThingsBoard installation failed

Tags: thingsboard

```
Starting ThingsBoard Installation...
Installing DataBase schema for entities...
Installing SQL DataBase schema part: schema-entities.sql
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:634)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:217)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:52)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:216)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.createDatabaseSchema(SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.java:66)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.install.SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.createDatabaseSchema(SqlAbstractDatabaseSchemaService.java:57)
        at org.thingsboard.server.install.ThingsboardInstallService.performInstall(ThingsboardInstallService.java:194)
        at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:597)
Unexpected error during ThingsBoard installation!
ThingsBoard installation failed!
```

Please help someone! I'm trying to install thingsBoard but installation failed, I have pasted the print from cmd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to: https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/3667.

1. Download from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html -> Other Versions the driver file:
   `postgresql-42.2.18.jar`
2. Copy it to: `c:/program files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot/jre/lib/ext/`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that postgre version 13 didn't support thingsboard. switching to postgre version 11 fixed the issue.